# Filemaker PHP API date range find

Tags: php, date, find, filemaker

I am trying to find a certain set of data from my Filemaker DB, for example

```
$fm = new FileMaker(****, ****, ****, ****);

$find = $fm->newFindCommand('MyLayout');

$find->addFindCriterion('Start_Date','07/01/2011');

$results = $find->execute();
```

This returns all of the data from my layout but does not use the find criterion.

any ideas?

Comment: I don't use Filemaker, but i think that date has incorrect format. For MySQl it is YYYY-MM-DD for the DATE type.

Comment: For FMP, dates are entered in MM/DD/YYYY format. Entering an invalid date will throw an error 500 - Date value does not meet validation entry options. You can use any FileMaker find format ">=1/1/2011" or "1/1/2011...3/1/2011" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check for an error before you show the results.

If $notFound = true then you could display some other message.

```
// check for an error in result
if (FileMaker::isError($results)) {
    if ($results->code != 401) {
      echo 'unable to find data: ' . $results->message . '(' . $results->code . ')';
      die();
    }
    else $notFound = true;
}
```